# Parent div is wider than its child text when the line breaks

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace

so, I thought I was quite good with CSS until I've lost a whole day trying to figure out such a tiny (and maybe obvious for many of you) problem.

Here is a fiddle to show roughly my structure: https://jsfiddle.net/dbcxv7pg/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">

    <li class="tab-link"><span>Digital Strategy</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Content Marketing</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>E-Mail Marketing</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Social Media</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Paid Search</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Paid Social</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>SEO</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Analysis &amp; Reporting</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Community Management</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>Influencer Marketing</span></li>
    <li class="tab-link"><span>UX</span></li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.tabs {
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding: 6px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
ul.tabs li {
    text-align:center;
}
```

As you can see, if the window is not wide enough to show the text on one line, the text will break into a new line, and that's fine as this is what I want.

But once the text breaks, some weird blank space appears on the right and left side of some text elements, causing the spacing between the items to be uneven:

[image]

I've tried playing around with white-space but that didn't seem to help.
Do you guys have any clue about how to remove this gap?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dez thanks but I don't get it, could you please elaborate? How could the ul padding affect the li's white space? I've tried setting the ul padding to 0 and I get the same behaviour. I'm not sure I understand what you mean though. Thanks!

Comment: The extra padding is because the lis are being stretched to try to share the space - and some are being stretched more than others making it look like you have uneven padding. It's something to do with how flex-basis shares out the space of the child flex items.  If you set it to 0, you will see justify content works properly but then your items are always at their smallest

Comment: @Pete you are the man, setting the flex-basis to 0 solved the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pete pointed out:

> The extra padding is because the **li**s are being stretched to try to share the space - and some are being stretched more than others making it look like you have uneven padding.
>
> It's something to do with how flex-basis shares out the space of the child flex items.
>
> If you set it to 0, you will see justify content works properly but then your items are always at their smallest

Thank you very much for claryfing, Pete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is just that when text breaks, longer words will have more white space on left and right side (because `text-align: center`) until they go back to one line again. That is creating uneven spacing between `li`'s in you code.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}

.a, .b {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a">Aasdfasdfasdfsdfasdfsasdf sdfdasdfssdfsdf</div>
  <div class="b">Bsdfsdf sdf</div>
</div>
```

One solution to remove this gap would be to set `word-break: break-all`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}

.a, .b {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a">Aasdfasdfasdfsdfasdfsasdf sdfdasdfssdfsdf</div>
  <div class="b">Bsdfsdf sdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nenad, thanks a lot for your time. I did think about this being an issue related to text-center before posting this question, however even if you provide the lis with `text-align:left` , the same problem will occur, just with the blank space sitting on the right rather than divided on the two sides :(

Comment: Thanks Nedad, but that breaks the word therefore not very practical for short headings. I do appreciate your effort, thank you very much, however Pete's comment already pointed me to the right direction :)